# Best books for self-studying differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, book-recommendation

Next semester (fall 2021) I am planning on taking a grad-student level differential topology course but I have never studied differential geometry which is a pre-requisite for the course. My plan is to self-study in the summer and this semester so that I do not have to waste a semester taking a differential geometry course which will ruin my schedule.

I am looking for a book that covers all of the following topics (ideally) but at least most of them:
[image: The sylbus]

any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: I suggest you "An Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry" by William M. Boothby

Comment: In my experience, the most important things for differential topology are smooth manifolds, tangent bundles and differentials, vector fields, flows of vector fields(!), some idea of what geodesics are and what the Riemannian exponential map does. Most things on your list kind of go into a different direction in the sense that they are designed to model and study _rigid geometric shapes_ whereas in differential topology you want to keep things loose and flexible. Do you know what topics are going to be covered in the course?

Comment: I liked the books of Loring Tu, they are concise and very clear.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you probably don't need to learn all of the topics listed in order to take the differential topology course. Could you list the topics covered in the latter course and the textbook used?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your vector calculus is fully mastered, and your linear algebra, at least at the level of acing an intro course in each. Solid foundations make all the difference.
My experience with Michael Spivak's *Differential Geometry* was unpleasant and required a lot of use of his *Calculus on Manifolds*, which some love but I strongly do not recommend.
A big book meant for physicists is Misner Thorne and Wheeler's *Gravitation*, which I think is decent for intuition building.
Unfortunately I haven't found a book on Differential Geometry that I actively like; MTW comes closest.

Answer (score 1):

I had a good experience with self study as an undergrad using “Differential Forms and Connections” by Darling. It covers much of what you mention, and does a good job building from curves and surfaces to smooth manifolds, vector bundles etc. I agree with the comments that some of the topics listed in your quote are more in the direction of geometry than topology, and wouldn’t be necessary in a course following, say, Guillemin/Pollack, Tu’s “Introduction to Manifolds” or Hirsch’s “Differential Topology”.

Answer (score 0):

Tristan Needham, who became quite famous for his "Visual Complex Analysis", has just published "Visual Differential Geometry". I haven't had a chance to read it yet myself, but knowing the author, it should prove to be a most excellent resource.